# How to add InfoWindow Object by using google static image map ?

Tags: google-maps-static-api

I want to add text labels to the image which i am getting from static google image api. Like a label and info window of all markers which is in simple google map.

I have seen the documentation, It is not documented clearly. Is it possible to display a infoWindow in `google Static Image API`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Marker labels or InfoWindows are not yet available for Google Maps Platform - Maps Static API.

But, we do have an existing feature request for this in our Google Issue Tracker. To express your interest and to subscribe you to its latest updates, I suggest that you star this entry: https://issuetracker.google.com/35818346

In the mean time, note that you could achieve something similar like this by using [Custom Icons](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#CustomIcons) that already have the labels. However, this solution may take a lot of time as you will first have to edit the icon image you'll use to include the label then host it somewhere.

Please see this sample request: 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x400&markers=icon:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/annkylah/TestRepo/master/icon2.png|anchor:26,68|scale:2|-35.281454,149.128545&markers=icon:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/annkylah/TestRepo/master/icon1.png|anchor:26,68|scale:2|-37.936915,145.169723&markers=icon:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/annkylah/TestRepo/master/icon3.png?raw=true|anchor:26,68|scale:2|-33.842312,150.983470&key=YOUR_API_KEY

[image: Sample Static Map]

Using [Google Charts - Image Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image) is also an option before, however, this service has been turned down last March 18, 2019.

> The limitation that you should also take note with the Custom Icon
>   workaround is that [you could only specify up to five unique custom
>   icons per Maps Static API
>   request](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#CustomIcons).
>   There's a feature request filed on Google Issue Tracker to [allow more
>   than 5 custom icons](https://issuetracker.google.com/35825584)
>   however, it was marked as a duplicate of another [feature request to
>   support KML layers in Static Maps
>   API](https://issuetracker.google.com/35817020).

I hope this helps!